# Нужна ли запятая после «тогда»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Тогда(,) ты доволен?

В значении «значит/следовательно».

Comment: У слова 'тогда' нет указанного вами значения (см. толковые словари).

Comment: Значения нет, а фразы с таким контекстом есть. Интересно. И как же тогда быть со знаками? Яснее не стало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Тогда – ты доволен?***

**ТОГДА,** нареч.  2. В таком случае, при таких условиях, обстоятельствах. Устал, т. отдохни. Раз согласны, т. начинайте. Не нервничай, т. всё получится.

Обычно "тогда" обозначает "в таком случае", поэтому значение "следовательно" должно быть понятно из контекста, например при противопоставлении антонимичной лексики.

Пример: *Ты не говоришь, что разочарован. Тогда – ты доволен?*

Для выражения такого значения (значит, следовательно) больше подходит **тире как более сильный знак**, запятой здесь будет недостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь понятна логика проставления знаков в таких случаях.